# Please just tell me if my working is correct.

Tags: probability-theory

It is known that $P(X = n) = p_n = \frac{2}{3^n}$

$X$ is the number of attempts needed to win the lottery.

The question: Find $P(X>5)$

My take:

$P(X>5) = 1 - P(X\leq 5)$ => is this correct?

$1 - P(X \leq 5) = 1 - (\frac{2}{3} + \frac{2}{3^2} + \frac{2}{3^3} + \frac{2}{3^4} + \frac{2}{3^5}) = \frac{1}{243}$

Comment: Looks good (expect for the company that runs this lottery).

Comment: Yes, it is correct.  Just show that $\sum_{1}^{\infty} P_n = 1$ to convince total probability is 1.

Comment: @satishramanathan: Isn't that true for any event in the known universe?

Comment: @barakmanos, I have worked out problems where it has violated this rule and yielded wrong solutions.  I can't remember staight out of my head.

Comment: Earlier on in the question, they stated to assume that but thanks for the heads up on ensuring for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah , its correct .

You can do in either way

$P(X>5)=\sum\limits_{i=6}^{\infty}(\dfrac{2}{3^i}) = 2*\sum\limits_{i=6}^{\infty}(\dfrac{1}{3})^i =2*\dfrac{(1/3)^6}{1-(1/3)}=\dfrac{1}{243}$

Since we have fact

$P(X\ge1)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}(\dfrac{2}{3^i})=2*\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}(\dfrac{1}{3})^i =2*\dfrac{(1/3)}{1-(1/3)}=1$

you can do

$P(X>r)=1-P(X\le r)$

Note : I used formula  $1+\dfrac{1}{r}+\dfrac{1}{r^2}+\cdots+(\dfrac{1}{r})^{\infty}=\dfrac{1}{1-(1/r)}$

Answer (score 1):

$$P(X\gt n)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac2{3^{n+k}}=\frac1{3^n}$$